# Subtracting two Numeric variables returning NA

Tags: r

```
set.seed(10003)
Niter <- 5
null_diff <- vector(length=Niter)
for (i in 1:Niter){
    households$ControlPermute <- sample(households$voted[households$treatment=='Control'], size=180002, replace=T)
    
    null_avg_treated <- mean(households$ControlPermute[households$treatment=='Neighbors'])
    null_avg_control <- mean(households$ControlPermute[df$treatment=='Control'])
    null_diff[i] <- null_avg_treated - null_avg_control

    print(null_avg_treated)
    print(null_avg_control)
    print(null_diff[i])
}
```

When I run this code with print statement, I get the following output

```
[1] 0.305814
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] 0.3055574
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] 0.3041573
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] 0.3048125
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] 0.3058008
[1] NA
[1] NA
```

I'm not sure why this is because there are numeric values assigned to the variables, but when they are printed and also subtracted to be stored in the vector null_diff, `NA` is returned

Comment: Change `mean(x)` to `mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why values are printed to the console but when they are actually subtracted they return NA though?

Comment: You weren't getting any NAs in the vector used to create `null_avg_treated` so that value is not `NA` and therefore prints as a number.  But you are getting NAs in the vector used to create `null_avg_control`, and so `null_avg_control` has the value `NA` and (as it must) prints as `NA`.  And when you subtract, you are taking the difference between a number (`null_avg_treated`) and an `NA` (`null_avg_control`), which is `NA`.

Comment: Also -- I cleaned up / organized your code in the question above.  Doing so makes it apparent that you use both `households$treatment` and `df$treatment`, which is probably incorrect, and may be causing you to get `NA`s where you didn't expect them.